# The layout in my profile page is broken

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

On my profile page for this site, the profile details on the top right, are shifted down - it looks like the HTML is broken somewhere. This doesn't happen on any other SE site.

It is not a problem as such, just that it looks wrong, and others may experience the same and wonder what is up.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: could you add in a screen grab? I'm not seeing the problem on my profile.

Comment: Added @MattЭллен

Comment: I'm using Chrome under XP - your profile displays correctly to me.

Comment: @SchroedingersCat What OS/browser are you using? I'm not having a problem on Chrome/7 either

Comment: Firefox. I suspect it is the profile that I see, not the one that is publically visible.

Comment: Are you still experiencing this behavior?

Comment: @JarrodDixon Yep.

Comment: @SchroedingersCat How did the smudge get on your email address?

Comment: @Danielδ - Paint.

Comment: What's it for?  You might want to touch it up a little, if you don't want people seeing your address.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I pushed a change that should hopefully fix your issue - I could never reproduce the problem, so let me know if it's fixed.

Comment: Fixed - thank you.

Comment: Really? You can't reproduce it but you 'fixed' it anyway?